# MongoDb "Working Set" exceeding RAM

Tags: mongodb, large-data

I m collecting timeseries in mongoDb. Eventually my working set will be larger than my RAM. However I mostly need to access the recent data.

If I put everything in just one table, would it still be possible to do that? Because the index size will keep growing if I just put all the data in one table.

I was thinking of creating a new table every month and put the data there. This way, the very old data will not be loaded in RAM unless someone (rarely) needs that archive data.

So my question is : is it better to manually partition the data like that or just leave everything up to mongoDB?